# SQL Server 2012 AlwaysOn Health Events in Dashboard

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have completed 6 installs of SQL Server 2012 SP1 and configured availability groups.

In the dashboard of all of my installs "View AlwaysOn Health Events" is greyed out and I'm not able to find another way to view the events that have occurred in the past regarding any availability groups.

I am familiar with the system DMV's to view current health status but I would like to view past events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found my answer.  The AlwaysOn Health Extended Event Seession off by default.  The following SQL enables the link in the dashboard.

```
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.server_event_sessions WHERE name = 'AlwaysOn_health')
    BEGIN
    ALTER EVENT SESSION AlwaysOn_health ON SERVER WITH (STARTUP_STATE = ON);
    END
    GO

    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.dm_xe_sessions WHERE name = 'AlwaysOn_health')
    BEGIN
    ALTER EVENT SESSION AlwaysOn_health ON SERVER STATE = START;
    END
    GO
```